# Data operation in BLOC

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I have a shopping application. I am trying to use the most recommended approach BLOC for the project.
Now I have a screen which contains three major parts

1. Categories list
2. Product list
3. Cart list

Now these subsections of that 1 screen have this operation

1. load/fetch
2. apply conditions or filter data
3. then multiple operations on loaded data

For example like I have a cart

Now in the cart, I have these operations

1. before adding a product to the cart there are multiple operations
   of filtering the data like if the product has discounts or not. if so
   then app discount and update price.
2. increment/decrement
3. edit

Now I am not getting the idea that should I?

1. The screen has 3 major sections like portions so should I use 3
   blocs of 1 bloc
2. most apps have examples like to load, show, success, and error type
   events and states so where will I apply these increment/decrements,
   and apply discount operations?
3. there may be a case where I will have to access the current data
   state from another class or file or bloc. so in short I want to hold
   the data to share across multiple screens

Answer (score 0):

For me, i associate every api request with a bloc.
so for example in your case, u have a Cart Page.
I would assume u have these few API requests,

```
GetCart
RemoveItemFromCart
UpdateItemQuantityInCartItem
```

So u will have then (using cubit)

```
GetCartCubit
RemoveItemFromCartCubit
UpdateItemQuantityInCartItemCubit
```

And each of this blocs can have a function called `request()` where you pass the data required for the api request and make an api request to a `repository` where u have your `client` API requests.

And each of this blocs will have states.

```
Initial
Requesting - state where api request made waiting for a response
Requested - state where there is a successful API response
Error - error state for when an API returns an error
```

You can check out this repo for a good example:
https://github.com/momoDragon/flutter_structure